# What coordinate system is this?

Tags: gps, coordinates

I need to convert this coordinate system to the GPS system or longitude/latitude. 
The problem is that i don't know what type of coordinates they are. First i thought they are NMEA coordinates, but they are a bit to long and they don't give the right values. I get this values from a database true a php call. I know what city the coordinates are but the values i got so far are not even close.

I get :

```
1740966.0365683099
5867224.681013038
```

what should i get (roughly) :

```
46.55620, 15.58582
```

Comment: How does these values get's to database?

Comment: this database is property of the local bus company. They enter it in but i have no contact whit them. This is a part of my graduation project and my mentor is currently away and i need to make this ASAP. They are the locations of bus stations. I thought they would be GPS but they are not.

Comment: Are you sure the coordinates are related to any geographic coordinate system? They look strange. They could be from an acad drawing just for display purposes (e,g map), I am pretty sure that nobody here will know. You have to ask the company what coordinate system that exactly is. Preferbaly they should give you the EPSG number of that projection. It is neither UTM, nor ETSR89, nor GausKrüger nor MGRS /UTMREF. You might ask at http://gis.stackexchange.com, too. You also might contact the Slovenian Country Survey authority. Or you conatct an geographic institute of your university

Answer (score 1):

They lood like they could be Decimal Degrees.
you should try look at this 
https://www.maptools.com/tutorials/lat_lon/formats

Comment: I thought they are too. But even if i take the first 2 numbers from 1740966.0365683099 i get 17 hours but the coordinates are at 15 hours.

Comment: I found that too when I inspected myself. Are you at an elevated altitude above sea level?
The results are suspiciously close but When you are talking co-ordinates then a few degrees can mean a huge difference

Comment: the altitude is about 288.0 meters above the sea level. I got no useful data when i converted this to hours, minutes and seconds but i got pretty close converting the expected data into seconds. The difference was about 2000 seconds.

Comment: seriously a downvote? It was a constructive attempt at answering the question. My rep is destroyed by petty downvotes like this. I give up on this.

Comment: This is not even close to decimal degress, think first before you write. If you know the answer then post it. But for speculations based on low know how of geo coordinates , you better use the comment field. The down vote system is made to mark wrong answers. And in your case it is wrong.

Comment: I had a thought and is it possible those are easting northing coordinates?

Comment: I would say figure out which Standard UTM Zone you are in and try converting your results to lat long using this http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/usefuldata/ConvertUTMNoOZ.HTM see how close you get.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers even the guesses. I tried that and i got UTM 
Easting: 545862.3 Northing: 5156228.2 Zone: 33. One of them is kinda close the other is way off.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably Spherical Mercator, the web mapping system used by Google amongst others. There's a clue in that the UTM conversion works in one axis, which means it's probably an easting northing type system with an origin on the equator.

You can use EPSG:900913 or EPSG:3857 to convert it.

Here's an example in Python using pyproj

```
from pyproj import transform,Proj
inProj = Proj(init='epsg:3857') # Spherical Mercator
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326') # Latitude / Longitude (WGS 84)
x1,y1 = 1740966.03,5867224.681
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print x2,y2
```

> > > 15.6393639388 46.5394669949

It's a surprising choice as this system tends to be looked down upon by professional cartographers (take a look at the history of the EPSG code 900913 for details).

It looks close enough to be in the same city, which is hopefully what you've used as your rough estimate for the co-ordinates.